# How can I slow the cold air coming in a furnace makeup vent?

Tags: furnace, vent

I've got an air vent from the outside which discharges right next to the furnace.  I know the furnace needs this air, but a glacial breeze comes through all the time.  I've found 3 options and I'm not sure which to do:

1. Extend the vent until its about 6" from the floor and put it in a 5 gallon bucket.
2. Add two elbows to make a 180 degree turn and extend it up 2 feet or so.
3. Do nothing.  I'd be crazy to try and change something that's been like this for the last 20 years.

Will option 1 or 2 actually help?  I'd prefer option 2 because its the more compact solution.

[image: furnace_with_makeup_vent]

Comment: Would a low tension damper work? I know they make powered dampers that can be wired into the furance blower as well

Comment: No, the vacuum on the room is so weak that it wouldn't overcome a damper--it would just draw from the rest of the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The makeup air ducts I've seen have been in a U-shaped arrangement where the exit end is high, near the ceiling. This leaves a puddle of cold air sitting in it that doesn't just fall out like it would here, whereas you essentially have a reverse chimney effect happening. It acts like a trap on a sink drain, and the slight vacuum that your furnace creates draws air from the duct as needed.

You could buy a length of 6" insulated flex duct and attach it to the existing outlet. Loop it back up and hang it near the ceiling. I'd also insulate the rigid duct with foil-faced fiberglass. You'll lose less heat to conduction.

Really, the outcome would be the same if you'd shorten the duct to a higher point and install a U-bend up high. There's no value in dropping it to the floor if you're just taking it all the way back up.

You could have success with the bucket idea, but the volume of the bucket outside the duct would need to be adequate to counter the weight of the air *in* the duct. That would take a large bucket.

Note: I'm not familiar with current code requirements on the subject.

Comment: The two elbows OP mentioned would do what you suggested - creating a U shaped arrangement.

Comment: The key to my suggestion is _height_. A U-bend alone doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thinking out loud here...What do you think those two closed off openings behind the PVC tubing are for?  You don't suppose they're for a fresh air intake to the combustion chamber?

Comment: And I see your point about the height.

Comment: Those are alternative access ports for right-side installation. Combustion air enters through the grille on the front.

Comment: @Isherwood, why would an air supply duct not go right into the furnace?  Why would it supply air from around the corner?  It seems like the fresh air supply should plug right into the front and the rest of the grille be taped off.  Maybe I am just jealous my furnace does not seem to have a fresh air duct.

Comment: That's not how they work. They aren't part of the HVAC system. They're part of the _room_. Modern direct-vent, high-efficiency furnaces have intake ducts like you describe. This isn't that. It merely restores air pulled into the furnace as a result of combustion and exhaustion. This prevents a vacuum on the home that can waste energy and cause other annoyances.

Comment: Yeah except this already causes wasted energy and is annoying. You can't draw combustion air from the same utility room as the equipment, but if it isn't a room (or if the door has a louver) ... I can't exactly remember what code says.

Comment: I thought the outlet needed to be close to the furnace.   Having it by the ceiling may be too far away.  Is it worth getting a hoyme damper installed? (Shuts the vent when the furnace is off.)

Comment: @isherwood - I find myself thinking about this more than is healthy.  What would be the downside of connecting the fresh air intake via dryer duct to the air intake for the furnace?  Let us not consider "looks like kludgy halfass fix" as a downside.   Outside air will still escape back out thru the grille to the room, but first the furnace will take all it needs.

Comment: *There is no air intake on your furnace.* The entire front vent is an intake, as are all the smaller openings and cracks. It's not designed to be a sealed unit. If you want a sealed unit, _buy_ a sealed unit. I won't advise you in hacking the situation in a way that may be unsafe. For one thing, I have no idea how it'll work. Over and out.