# Can these vents be covered or removed?

Tags: hvac, furnace, water-heater

This vent in our laundry/mudroom has two huge openings and vents directly outside (pictures linked at the end). When we bought the house, both openings were covered with a plastic film. During our inspection, it was recommended that we remove the plastic to provide airflow to this room, because our water heater and furnace are located in this room. So we did. But now it's been getting down to -15F at night, and I'm second guessing the decision to remove the coverings. The water heater and furnace have their own combustion pipes venting out. In that case, are these necessary? Are they old vents from a previous set up? Could I perhaps cover and keep a carbon monoxide detector in this room to monitor?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or this? [How can I slow the cold air coming in a furnace makeup vent?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/213684/35141)

Comment: Or this? [Should my furnace closet have this duct opening into the unconditioned vented attic?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/41398/35141)

Comment: If the waterheater and furnace both have intake and exhaust pipes (sealed combustion) you don't need the vents, If they **only** have exhaust pipes, intake air comes from the outside intake pipe.

Comment: How is your clothes dryer vented?

Answer (score 0):

So it's a Laundry-room as well as a furnace and water heater room.

If the dryer uses gas, that's a **third** fuel burning appliance in one small room. Even if it doesn't, that's a big fan in a small room to cause backdrafting of the other gas appliances, without make-up-air available.

Looks to me like the vent is required, but you could possibly route it so that the incoming air is directed closer to the air intakes of the appliances that use it.

Comment: Someone else can feel free to look up the relevant code on required venting and post an answer - I'll probably upvote it. Irrelevant to me so I'm not familiar enough with it and it's a bit to wade through on a quick look. ;^)